# Downloadable products not working on pwa venia storefrontend

Tags: pwa, venia, downloadable-product

It appears that the downloadable products bundle and grouped products are not functioning properly in the PWA Venia setup. I have examined the Vue frontend, and it seems there is no support for downloadable products. Despite the Vue Storefront documentation clearly indicating support, there is no mention of it in the Adobe documentation. Could you please provide guidance on enabling downloadable products for the PWA Venia setup? Your assistance in resolving this matter is greatly appreciated